# Using regular jquery syntax within jquerymobile code?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with this line - $('#container1').html(html); if i use alert(html); it shows the html fine but the problem is putting the html into container1 div. how is this possible? i am new to jquerymobile so i'm not sure if i am doing something wrong, is it not possible to use regular jquery syntax anymore?

**jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 10; // More than this horizontal displacement, and we will suppress scrolling.
    $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 30; // Swipe horizontal displacement must be more than this.
    $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold = 500; // More time than this, and it isn't a swipe.
    $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 75; // Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.

    $(document).on("swipeleft", function () {
        alert('test');
        $.get('notifications.php').success(function (html) {
            $('#container1').html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header">

<a href="#left-panel" class="jqm-navmenu-link  ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext" data-role="button" role="button" data-theme="c">Menu</a>

<h1>Edit Contact</h1>

<a href="#right-panel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-user jqm-navmenu-link   ui-alt-icon ui-btn-right  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-nodisc-icon" data-role="button" role="button" data-theme="c">Menu</a>

<div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="notif" data-icon="custom" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="email" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="freq" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>



<div data-role="content">

        <!--
        Place the Container here because
        jQuery Mobile data-role="page" defines a browser fullscreen page 
        (the dataroles are rules for formating a page and there can be only one visible page)
        -->
        <div  id="container1"></div>
    </div>  


<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="left-panel">

</div>

<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="b">

    <p>Right push panel.</p>
    <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Close</a>

</div><!-- /panel -->


</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: `$("#container1").load("file.php");` should work for you.

Comment: surprisingly it does not work.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors just no response. the $.get worked and showed me the html in an alert box although with .load i just get no response.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qhy2u/show/ swipeleft to see it working

Answer (score 1):

First off, modifying [*Global Settings*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/) should be done during `mobileinit` event. This event fires after loading jQuery JS libraries, hence, you need to do any changes before loading jQuery Mobile Library.

```
<script src="jquery.js></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.extend($.event.special.swipe, {
          scrollSupressionThreshold: 10,
          horizontalDistanceThreshold: 30,
          durationThreshold: 500,
          verticalDistanceThreshold: 75
      });
  });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js></script>
```

For loading contents from an *external* file, use `$.get` with `html` option and then *initialize* elements by calling `.enhanceWithin()`.

Don't forget to wrap your code in `pagecreate`, it is equivalent to `.ready()`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $(document).on("swipeleft", function () {
        $.get("URL", function (data) {
            $("#container1").html(data).enhanceWithin();
        }, "html");
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qhy2u/show/)**